# A GtkEntry signal emitting at focus change

Tags: pygtk, glade

I'm writing a very simple app using Glade and PyGtk. In the app, I need to collect user inputs and parse it as a conf file. In order to dump all the freetext user inputs to a StringIO, I am using the `on_xxxxxxxx_activate` signal.This solution requires the user to hit Enter for the signal to be emitted. Instead I would like to use a signal which emits on focus change (switching to any other field). Does PyGtk provide a signal like that?

**Addendum**:

The behaviour I am looking for here is the one used by `gtk_editable_insert_text`. Is there a way of linking a `GtkEditable`'s signal to `GtkEntry`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gtk.Entry` implements the `gtk.Editable` interface, so you can use those methods on your entry widget without problems. But if I understand your question correctly, you don't want the `insert_text` signal. You should rather use the [`focus-out-event`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwidget.html#signal-gtkwidget--focus-out-event).

Comment: `focus-out-event` is exactly what I need, but isn't it a Boolean? I mean doesn't it return a True/False result? Also implementing in the code gives an error `on_servername_focus_out_event() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`. Even though only two arguments are used.

Comment: Actually, ignore that comment.I fixed it by putting a 3rd argument into the functions, in this case `on_servername_focus_out_event(self, widget, list)`. Thank you for your help! ;)

Comment: A signal/event doesn't return anything, it is just called when the connected event is emitted. The second (or third in a method) argument is the event, not a list. So it becomes: `on_servername_focus_out_event(self, widget, event)`